# Finding explicit unimodular transformations for Chern-Simons K-matrices

Tags: condensed-matter, computational-physics, topological-order, quantum-hall-effect, chern-simons-theory

An invertible, symmetric matrix with integer entries, $K$, that encodes the braiding and statistics of an Abelian topologically ordered state, is equivalent to another such matrix, $K'$, if there exists an integer unimodular matrix, $W$, such that $$W^T K W = K'$$
Suppose I have $K$ and $K'$ and want to find such a $W$. Does there exist a general procedure for finding this? I can't find a particularly clever way of doing it. However, it seems that perhaps people know how to do this since in -

http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.6256 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.5708

they find large $W$ matrices (even $10\times 10$). I would like to know if this can only be done generally in certain cases (in systems with no topological order i.e. det$|K| = 1$) or of there is a known procedure for finding such a transformation for any $K$.

See also - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800488/existence-of-unimodular-congruence-transformation-for-symmetric-integer-matrice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Necessary and sufficient condition for conjugacy**: see [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia). In your notation, the two symmetric matrices $K$ and $K'$ are conjugate by a transformation $W^TKW = K'$ if and only if they have the same number of positive and negative eigenvalues (no null eigenvalues since both are nonsingular). The eigenvalues themselves need not be identical though.

**Necessary and sufficient condition for $W$ to be unimodular**: $K$ need not be unimodular, but the conjugacy relation imposes
$$
[\det(W)]^2 = \frac{\det(K')}{\det(K)}
$$
so $W$ is unimodular if and only if 
$$
\det(K) = \det(K')
$$

**Finding transformation $W$**: Diagonalize $K$ and $K'$ as 
$$
K = U^T Q U,\;\;\;\;,U^TU = UU^T = I\;\;\;\;\;Q=Q^T=\text{Diag}(\lambda_K)
$$
$$
K' = {U'}^T{Q'}{U'}, \;\;\;\;\;{U'}^T{U'} = {U'}{U'}^T = I\;\;\;\;\;{Q'}={Q'}^T= \text{Diag}(\lambda_{K'})
$$
where the diagonal matrices $Q$, $Q'$ list the eigenvalues $\lambda_K$, $\lambda_{K'}$ in order, say from smallest to largest. Further define $S = \text{Diag}(\sqrt{|\lambda_K|})$, ${S'} = \text{Diag}(\sqrt{|\lambda_{K'}|})$, and rewrite 
$$
Q = S^T D S,\;\;\;\;\; Q' = {S'}^T D {S'}
$$
where $$D = \text{Diag}(\text{sign}(\lambda_K)) = \text{Diag}(\text{sign}(\lambda_{K'}))$$ is now a diagonal unimodular matrix, $[\det(D)]^2 = 1$. Substituting everything into the conjugacy relation brings it to the form
$$
(S U W)^T D (S U W) =  ({S'}{U'})^T D ({S'}{U'})
$$
and allows the identification, for instance,
$$
S U W = {S'}{U'}
$$
which eventually gives
$$
W = U^T S^{-1}{S'}{U'}
$$
If $\det(K) = \det(K')$ then also $\det(S) = \det(S')$ and so $\det(W) = \pm 1$, depending on $\det(U)$, $\det(U')$.

Note however that $W$ is not unique. Any ${\bar W} = U^T S^{-1}V{S'}{U'}$ with $V$ such that $V^TDV = D$ (for example $[V, D] = [V^T, D] = 0$ and $V^TV = I$) works just as well.

Comment: @udvr So to ensure that $W$ only has integer entries, you have to adjust $V$ until this is satisfied?

Comment: Sorry, I realised now that I hadn't specified that I want $W$ to be integer valued.

Comment: That one seems to be a hard(er) one. But there is a bunch of related questions on Mathoverflow, maybe you can find something helpful over there. See 2nd answer of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/70528/symmetric-integer-matrices  (outlines an algorithm), and also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/97448/canonical-form-of-symmetric-integer-matrix-m (has interesting refs, but kinda out of my comfort zone). Hope this helps  bit :)